# Como passar um parâmetro junto com o Model para uma PartialVIew ao renderizá-la

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Para criar alguns campos dinamicamente, estou utilizando um for e renderizando. 
Ao chamar a Partial _Contato, gostaria de passar o valor [i] do índice do for para eu ordenar os campos. Não está funcionando... Está dando erro na página... alguém sabe como me ajudar?
Um abraço!

Erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gerando os campos:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PessoasContatosViewModel.Count; i++)
{
   @await Html.PartialAsync("_Contato", Model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i], new ViewDataDictionary { { "indice", i } })
}
```

Recebendo a Model e o Parâmetro na PartialView _Contato:

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaContatoViewModel
@{
    string valuePassedIn = this.ViewData.ContainsKey("indice") ? this.ViewData["indice"].ToString() : "0";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque:

```js
@await Html.PartialAsync("_Contato", Model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i], new ViewDataDictionary { { "indice", i } })
```

Por:

```js
   @await Html.PartialAsync("_Contato", Model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i], new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData){ { "indice", i } })
```

Comment: você é o cara!!!! Muito, muito obrigado :)